# How to get a stable random number in a range given a seed?

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have:

- a seed – an integer number, e.g. 1200303
- a range for target values [1, 20]

Is there a mathematical way to get a random number in the `[1, 20]` range that is determined by the seed?

i.e.

```
rand(seed int, range [int, int]);
rand(1, [1, 20]); // "4"
rand(1, [1, 20]); // "4" (if seed and range is the same, I expect the same value)
rand(1, [1, 21]); // "6" (changing range changes random number)
rand(2, [1, 20]); // "9" (changing seed changes random number)
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out, I have been looking for what is called a pseudorandom number generator (PRNG).

There are many PRNG implementations. Mersenne Twister is the most popular but also has fairly weak security properties.

I went with https://www.npmjs.com/package/seeded-rand

```
const SEED = 123,
const LOWER_RANGE = 1;
const UPPER_RANGE = 100;

const srand = new Srand(SEED_ID);
const gifId = srand.intInRange(LOWER_RANGE, UPPER_RANGE);
```

This will provide a number between 1 and 100 that is deterministic, i.e. multiple program executions will return the same number given the same seed.

---

#### Update

Turns out my original attempt is not as random as I thought it to be.

https://github.com/DomenicoDeFelice/jsrand/issues/3

The solution is to hash the seed first, e.g.

```js
import {
  createHash,
} from 'crypto';
import Srand from 'seeded-rand';

const seed = createHash('sha1').update(String(SEED)).digest().readUInt32BE();

new Srand(seed).intInRange(1, UPPER_RANGE);
```

If you only need 1 determinstically random value per seed, then you don't need the random function at all here. Just do `seed % UPPER_RANGE` (see below).

---

Many PRNGs allow you to specify an output range; if not, they are usually from 0 (inclusive) to 1 (exclusive) and it's sufficient to basically do:

```
let range = (max - min);

Math.floor(value * range) + min
```

If you are taking this path, make sure to double-check that the chosen implementation is not 1 inclusive because then it will very occasionally overshoot the max.

Also, if you are okay with a recognizable pattern of predictability, then you can just use `SEED % UPPER_RANGE`, i.e.

```js
123 % 20; // "3"
124 % 20; // "4"
// ...
164 % 20; // "4"
```

Thanks to *joepie91* from Freenode for his guidance. I am just documenting his advice.

Comment: Most implementations of random number generators *are* pseudo-random.  Java's Random [takes a seed](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#Random-long-), as does [the .NET Framework's Random class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.-ctor?view=netcore-3.1#System_Random__ctor_System_Int32_) and many others.  To get truly random numbers, you need a thermal noise generator, an alpha particle source, or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a concept of how to do this using simple math and loops. I'm sure the details can be improved, but in general, did you want something like this?

```js
// Seed random (pseudo-random)
const seedRand = (num, range) => {
  // Generate number multiplication
  num = String(num).split('').reduce((c, n) => (n != 0) ? c * n : c * c);
  // Transform to match range
  let s = range[0],
      e = range[1]
  while(num < range[0] || num > range[1]) {
    if(num > range[1]) num = Math.floor(num / e--);
    if(num < range[0]) num = Math.floor(num * s++);
  }
  // Return value
  return num;
}

// Test
console.log(seedRand(1220501, [1, 20]));
console.log(seedRand(1520502, [1, 20]));
console.log(seedRand(1520502, [1, 20])); // Same seed as previous one
console.log(seedRand(1370503, [1, 20]));
console.log(seedRand(1370503, [1, 21])); // Same seed as previous one, different range
```